# Favourite/ignored topics bubbles broken

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, bookmarks

It appears as though the bubbles containing the favourite/ignored topics are missing a side:

[image: Illustrative photo]

Is this a new bug in `rev 2011.5.9.4`?

**Edit:** I'm using `Chrome 12.0.742.30 dev`. Works in Safari.

Comment: Works for me in FF 4.0.1, which browser are you using?

Comment: @DMA Updated the question. I'm using Chrome, and I'm looking for any bugs that were opened recently (although it has worked since the latest Chrome update, and the only thing that changed was (presumably, based off the version number) the site design).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always been this way in Chrome -- doesn't happen in IE9, FF4, Opera, etc.

So it's really a chrome quirk.

Comment: That's strange; I've never noticed it before. But I suppose I'll take your word for it.

Comment: I have no problem with it in Chrome, using the latest version.

Comment: this happens to me in Chrome as well http://i.imgur.com/mOqzK.png

Comment: "Same here" post, but @nhinkle what do you mean by latest version? Normal channel or Beta/Dev?

Comment: @slhck using the mainstream normal release channel, version 11.0.696.68.

Comment: That is, it works fine for me in the normal release channel of Chrome, and beta/dev versions have never been officially supported.

Comment: I'm seeing it on all sites - it's just more noticeable on Super User.